# Changing background color in easy gui

Tags: python-2.7, easygui

I did not find any useful link that talks about how to change the background color in easygui.
Is there a way to change the background color in EASY GUI ?

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry, there is not way to set the background color.

At the moment, easygui has an easy interface, but is not as powerful as many users want.  We hope to change that in the future and have added your question as an enhancement:

https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/issues/49

In order to do what you want you should build your GUI using another framework.  I would suggest Tkinter, not because its the for-sure best, but because it is also simple and fairly standard.  You can look at the source code in easygui.py on how it was done previously, or search for 'tkinter' in your favorite Internet browser.